# Regular expression test ; (\bSubject:\b)(?!=\bSubject:test.com\b)

Tags: regex, postfix-mta

Ok I need this to be working.

As postfix bodycheck go through each line...I need some sort of if else.

If this is subject line and I want to check subject and NOT `subject:test.com` to be true

```
(\bSubject:\b)(?!=\bSubject:test.com\b)
```

This is not working.

Sample line:

```
Subject:test.com - testing email
```

Answer (score 0):

If the lookahead is supported, you could write the pattern as:

```
\bSubject:(?!test\.com\b).*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e3yKTJ/1)